# Is it conventional for Swift UIViewController implementations to use default property values, or to initialize properties in viewDidLoad?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, initialization

In a Swift implementation of a `UIViewController`, we have the opportunity to use default property values instead of having to conduct the `UIViewController` initializer ceremony. For example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let model = SomeModelObject()
```

What are the impacts of this approach, rather than instantiating the model property in, say, `viewDidLoad`? Example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var model: SomeModelObject?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        model = SomeModelObject()
```

If the object being assigned to the property is always instantiated in a known manner, wouldn't just setting a default property value make more sense rather than making it an optional and assigning it a value within `viewDidLoad`? In an oC implementation, we'd typically implement an `init`, and use the `if ([super init])` idiom to conditionally initialize the controller properties. However, it seems that most of the sample code from Apple, at the time of this writing, doesn't follow this idiom in Swift with default property values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still too early to say what's conventional in Swift. We're still all making it up. And Apple's sample code is a notoriously bad guide (the Programming Guides have always been the better thing to follow). Reading the devforums is generally a better way to see what the Swift team thinks is good Swift (but styles are changing as the language changes).

Assigning values in the declaration is probably going to be the best approach in many cases, as long as you can do it. Some things aren't available until `viewDidLoad`, so you can't initialize those earlier.

In ObjC, it is not that great to put things in `init`, since very often `init` is not called. You wind up having to put things in both `init` and `initWithCoder:` (which means that you need to hoist initialization into another method like "setup"). There's also a bit of song-and-dance around how `init` integrates with `initWithNibName:bundle:` that can bite you since that's the designated initializer (not `init`). You have to be very careful.

All that often leads ObjC code to put most initialization in `viewDidLoad`, since it's more reliable (at least since iOS 6 when they got rid of `viewDidUnload`).

The point of all that is that this isn't a simple question even in ObjC. But in Swift, I'd say the better place to put model things is in default initializers, like you say, and do the rest in `viewDidLoad` like in ObjC. But we're all still figuring it out.

Comment: If you know where your VC is coming from, and you should, you'll know what initializer is called. So you usually only need `initWithCoder:` for VCs from storyboards, for instance.